# Add formatting to a YAML value with yq v4

Tags: aws-cloudformation, yq

I'm trying to use yq https://github.com/mikefarah/yq v4.3.2 to add a yaml value in a CloudFormation template like so:

```
Mappings: 
  RegionMap: 
    us-east-1: 
      AMI: 'ami-YeahRight'
```

Instead, what I'm getting is:

```
Mappings: 
  RegionMap: 
    us-east-1: 
      AMI: ami-YeahRight
```

The style bits in the documentation and from this SO answer [yq processing a string with quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62198943/yq-processing-a-string-with-quotation-marks?) made me think that this portion of a bash script would work however the style portion is ignored.

```
region="us-east-1"
ami="ami-YeahRight"
echo Inserting $ami into $region
yq eval '.Mappings.RegionMap.'"$region"'.AMI='"$ami"' style="single"' -i temp.yaml
```

I've tried a whole bunch of similar bits but can't seem to crack this nut. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mikefaraq/yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) is going through major leap of changes starting from v4 and I'm not surprised that things are breaking in-between.

On v4.4 I can make this work, but [using `env()` function](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators#dynamic-key-lookup-with-environment-variable) to look-up the variables and use the [`..style` attribute](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/style#set-single-quote-style) to set the quoting style

```sh
region="us-east-1" ami="ami-YeahRight" yq e '.Mappings.RegionMap.[env(region)] = env(ami) | ..style="single"' yaml
```

Comment: You're not kidding about the leap of changes! So I ended up keeping the beginning of the eval string the same for reasons but changing the end to ```| ..style="single"``` worked like a charm. Cheers!